# Center and Resize Buttons

Tags: html, css, layout

[image]

```
#controlpanel .button 
{

    margin: 12px 12px 0px 12px;
     width: 100%;
}
```

How do I make these buttons fill the width of the white box, and yet have 12px on each side? Padding adds space internally... and margin makes them go off the white box.

Comment: Have you tried adding padding to the white box?

Answer (score 1):

1. add padding to #controlpanel
2. remove left and right margins from button
3. add box-sizing:border-box to buttons
   and you should get smth like:

   ```
   #controlpanel{     
       padding:0px 12px 12px 12px;
   }


   #controlpanel .button {
       margin: 12px 0px 0px 0px;
       width: 100%;
       box-sizing:border-box;
       -o-box-sizing:border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
       -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
   }
   ```

Comment: you're right, it's enough to remove left and right margins and add padding to outer div

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `width: 100%;`.
Try to comment out that line and type: `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

Two things may help:

- use *padding* for `div#controlpanel`
- remove the *margin* for buttons

In addition you could also try to remove the 100% width.